# What visio template can I use top provide a physical design that will meet the specifications outlined in the systems requirement document?

Tags: visio

What visio template can I use top provide a physical design that will meet the specifications outlined in the systems requirement document?

I need to create a physical design but I'm not sure what visio template to use to do this.  Any help?

Thanks,
JB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "physical design" you mean PCB layout, then no such built-in template exists, and Visio is not exactly a tool to create PCB layouts. You could try googling for some third-party stencils though.

Comment: Ok thank you, appreciate it. I will give that a shot. :)